# jQuery .load() function not working on my php file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web-applications, web

My particular situation with using the jQuery .load() function is to include a page into my site after clicking a link. I have chosen to write the code inline.  What I have is a user control panel with several buttons that would link to pages that you edit your information.  I have one for password and one for settings.  I'm trying to get this one to work and I will write a for each loop to apply to any more links I click.  My php file looks like this:

```
<?php
    include_once("template/main_site/core/init.php");
    protect_page();

    if (empty($_POST) === false) {
        $required_fields = array('current_password', 'password', 'password_again');
        foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
            if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
                $errors[] = 'Fields lighted red are required.';
                break 1;
            }
        }

        if (encryptBetter($_POST['current_password']) === $user_data['password']) {
            if (trim($_POST['password']) !== trim($_POST['password_again'])) {
                $errors[] = 'Your new passwords do not match';
            }
            if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6 || strlen($_POST['password']) >= 32) {
                $errors[] = 'Your new password must be less than 32 characters and more than 6 characters.';
            }
        } else {
            $errors[] = 'Your current password is entered incorrectly.';
        }

    }
?>
    <h1>Change Password</h1>
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
        echo 'Your password has been changed!';
    } else {
        if (isset($_GET['force']) === true && empty($_GET['force']) === true) {
    ?>
        <p>You must change your password now that you've requested.</p>
    <?php
        }
        if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
            change_password($session_user_id, trim($_POST['password']));
            header('Location: changepassword.php?success');
            exit();
        } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
            echo output_errors($errors);
        }
    ?>
    <form action = "" method = "post">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>Current Password</label>
                <input required type = "password" name = "current_password" pattern=".{6,32}"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>New Password</label>
                <input required type = "password" name = "password" pattern=".{6,32}"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Repeat New Password</label>
                <input required type = "password" name = "password_again" pattern=".{6,32}"/>
            </li>
            <input type = "submit" value = "change password"/>
        </ul>
    </form>

<?php
    }
?>
```

I have this php file included in a containing page.  I also note that if I include the changepassword.php page using php include, it will load properly.  I basically want the same thing as php's include, except with jQuery load.

My logged in included php file looks like this:

```
<div id="controls">
    <ul>
        <a id = "changepassword" href = "#login"><li>Change Password</li></a>
        <a href = "#"><li>Edit Profile</li></a>
        <?php if (is_admin()) { ?><a href = "#admin"><li>Administrate</li></a><?php }?>
        <a href = "logout.php"><li>Log out</li></a>
        <div id = "panel"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id = "panel"><?php # include_once('template/main_site/includes/widgets/changepassword.php'); ?></div>

<script>
    $('#changepassword').click(function() {
        var phpFile = 'template/main_site/includes/widgets/' + $(this).attr('id') +'.php';
        $('#panel').html('loading...').load(phpFile);
    });
</script>
```

If I'm being an idiot, you can troll me. I don't care.  If it's a security block in jQuery, let me know.  I read the documentation for load a lot of times to try to find out why it doesn't work.  If I just can't do it, I want this community to tell me so I can give up.  I really just want a live include of these files. There probably is another solution for me. If so, suggest it.  I can try to build it.  Thank you.

Comment: is this `template/main_site/includes/widgets/` real path? can you open the URL within browser that you try to load it using jquery?

Comment: ` <?php if (is_admin() === true) { ?><a href = "#admin"><li>Administrate</li></a><?php }?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#changepassword').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var phpFile = 'template/main_site/includes/widgets/' + $(this).attr('id') +'.php';
        $.get(phpFile,{},function(response) {
            $('#panel').html(response);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

You'll need to wrap the script so that it can be executed as soon as the DOM is ready.

Comment: Try the addition of the `.preventDefault()` method on the event.

Comment: You know that this script will not load into the DOM until the `.php` file it is contained within is loaded, right?

Comment: Ok.. one more change - you'll need to monitor the console to see what's going on...

Comment: It really sounds like you're not getting the response you are expecting from the `changepassword.php` script.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the jQuery [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function. This function executes your script once DOM is fully loaded. So wrap your whole script inside it.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#changepassword').click(function() {
        var phpFile = 'template/main_site/includes/widgets/' + $(this).attr('id') +'.php';
        $('#panel').html('loading...').load(phpFile);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @bjames105: what results are you getting on click event when using this script?

Comment: did u check browser console? Are you getting any error there?

Comment: that's not a bad idea of using jQuery tabs... :)